# arrays, pointers and pointers to functions in finite-state-machine

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, state-machine

I was reading this: http://johnsantic.com/comp/state.html and having hard time comprehending this part:

```
void (*const state_table [MAX_STATES][MAX_EVENTS]) (void) = {

    { action_s1_e1, action_s1_e2 }, /* procedures for state 1 */
    { action_s2_e1, action_s2_e2 }, /* procedures for state 2 */
    { action_s3_e1, action_s3_e2 }  /* procedures for state 3 */
};
```

Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: http://cdecl.org/ can be of help.

Comment: @another.anon.coward  No it can't. Syntax error. That site is generally rather bad at handling valid C code, in my experience.

Comment: @Lundin well, it doesn't know the defines. If you replace them by numbers, it works well.

Comment: cdecl.org: void (*const state_table [][]) (void)  => declare state_table as array of array of const pointer to function (void) returning void

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It defines 2D array of pointers functions (return void).

`state_table [MAX_STATES][MAX_EVENTS]` means that `state_table` is 2D array, and the `void (*expression)(void)` means that `expression` is pointer to a function, that takes no arguments (this is the mean of `(void)` as argument list), and returns `void`.

The other lines just initializes the array.

Comment: Function which takes no arguments & returns void :)

Answer (score 1):

If you un-ofuscate the code with a typedef, it actually becomes readable:

```
typedef void (*const fptr_state) (void);

fptr_state  state_table [MAX_STATES][MAX_EVENTS] = 
{
    { action_s1_e1, action_s1_e2 }, /* procedures for state 1 */
    { action_s2_e1, action_s2_e2 }, /* procedures for state 2 */
    { action_s3_e1, action_s3_e2 }  /* procedures for state 3 */
};
```